# Concatenate data and base does not work as expected

Tags: sha1, hmacsha1, pkcs11interop

I have a key in HSM

I want to derive another key from it and use it to SHA1 HMAC some data

my problem is that `CKM_CONCATENATE_DATA_AND_BASE` mechanism does not work as expected.

I think it work as below:

if my key **(BASE)** is **"11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88"** and I want to add **"00"** **(DATA)** to its start i want to new key be **"00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88"** but generated (and saved) key is **"00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77"**

derived key length will not change and one byte from end of original key will drop!

what should I do?

I try to add `ObjectAttribute VALUE_LEN`. but derived key length doesn't change.

```
    static void PkcsTest()
        {
            string p11lib = "_pkcs11.dll";
            var factories = new Pkcs11InteropFactories();
            var library = factories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(factories, p11lib, AppType.MultiThreaded);
            var slots = library.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent);
            var slot = slots[0];
            var session = slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadWrite);
            session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, "123456");

            var data = new byte[] { 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f };
            var originalKey = new byte[]{0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88,0x99};
            var dataToAddToKey = new byte[] { 0x00 };
            //Import key to HSM
            var objectAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>
            {
                session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_SECRET_KEY),
                session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_GENERIC_SECRET),
                session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_VALUE,originalKey ),
                session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_DERIVE,true ),
            };
            var originalKeyHandler = session.CreateObject(objectAttributes);
            //creating extended key
            var mechanismParams = session.Factories.MechanismParamsFactory.CreateCkKeyDerivationStringData(dataToAddToKey);
            var mechanismType = session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_CONCATENATE_DATA_AND_BASE, mechanismParams);
            var extendedKeyHandler = session.DeriveKey(mechanismType, originalKeyHandler, null);
            //generating SHA1 HMAC 
            var hmacMechanism = session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_SHA_1_HMAC);
            var hash = session.Sign(hmacMechanism, extendedKeyHandler, data);
            //expected : 04FE079DA27D1D8A8EB812A0BCBE1D264D0A6D7C
            //result   : 31A559C06CE465831D354A3EE058A1C519180E87
        }
```

here's my result using `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1`:

```
data is "0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f" in all tests
```

```
KEY:1122334455667788112233445566778899 
HASH: F1D20BBBDD3D07D883827F64A55DB58BD2136C9F
KEY:001122334455667788112233445566778899 
HASH: 04FE079DA27D1D8A8EB812A0BCBE1D264D0A6D7C
KEY:0011223344556677881122334455667788 
HASH:31A559C06CE465831D354A3EE058A1C519180E87
```

and my result using `PKCS` with **"1122334455667788112233445566778899"** as `original key`

```
Sign with Original Key : F1D20BBBDD3D07D883827F64A55DB58BD2136C9F
sign with derived key  : 31A559C06CE465831D354A3EE058A1C519180E87
```

```
expected result        : 04FE079DA27D1D8A8EB812A0BCBE1D264D0A6D7C
```

UPDATE 1:

key size after Derive with Concatenate mechanism always stays same as original key. I try to add data AFTER key (with CKM_CONCATENATE_BASE_AND_DATA) with any size of data and nothing happened. the derived key and original key are same. because HSM adds n bytes to original key and drop that again (so that key size stay same which I dont want to)

if any one has an example of derive a key using CKM_CONCATENATE_BASE_AND_DATA please let me know

Comment: Can key be any arbitrary length? If that's the case, then if data were 30 bytes, that would be a much larger key after concatenation.

Comment: What happens if you don't specify a key type? Looking at the documentation, specifying a type will limit it to the type's length https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v211/group__SEC__12__41__3__CONCATENATION__OF__DATA__AND__A__BASE__KEY.html

Comment: @Anthony my real usage is 48 byte key as BASE and 2 bytes as DATA to derive. then final key must be be 50 bytes. but I simplified problem for stackoverflow.

Comment: If I don't specify key type I get inconsistent template error or something